# How can I change the installation path of an autotools-based Bitbake recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have an autotools-based BitBake recipe which I would like to have binaries installed in `/usr/local/bin` and libraries installed in `/usr/local/lib` (instead of `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib`, which are the default target directories).

Here's a part of the `autotools.bbclass` file which I found important.

```
CONFIGUREOPTS = " --build=${BUILD_SYS} \
                  --host=${HOST_SYS} \
                  --target=${TARGET_SYS} \
                  --prefix=${prefix} \
                  --exec_prefix=${exec_prefix} \
                  --bindir=${bindir} \
                  --sbindir=${sbindir} \
                  --libexecdir=${libexecdir} \
                  --datadir=${datadir} \
                  --sysconfdir=${sysconfdir} \
                  --sharedstatedir=${sharedstatedir} \
                  --localstatedir=${localstatedir} \
                  --libdir=${libdir} \
                  ...
```

I thought that the easiest way to accomplish what I wanted to do would be to simply change `${bindir}` and `${libdir}`, or perhaps change `${prefix}` to `/usr/local`, but I haven't had any success in this area.  Is there a way to change these installation variables, or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

---

### Update:

#### Strategy 1

As per Ross Burton's suggestion, I've tried adding the following to my recipe:

```
prefix="/usr/local"
exec_prefix="/usr/local"
```

but this causes the build to fail during that recipe's `do_configure()` task, and returns the following:

```
| checking for GLIB... no
| configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.12.3) were not met:
| 
| No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

This package can be found during a normal build without these modified variables. I thought that adding the following line might allow the system to find the package metadata for glib:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH = " ${STAGING_DIR_HOST}/usr/lib/pkgconfig  "
```

but this seems to have made no difference.

#### Strategy 2

I've also tried Ross Burton's other suggestion to add these variable assignments into my distribution's configuration file, but this causes it to fail during `meta/recipes-extended/tzdata`'s `do_install()` task. It returns that `DEFAULT_TIMEZONE is set to an invalid value.` Here's the source of the error from `tzdata_2015g.bb`

```
# Install default timezone
if [ -e ${D}${datadir}/zoneinfo/${DEFAULT_TIMEZONE} ]; then
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
    echo ${DEFAULT_TIMEZONE} > ${D}${sysconfdir}/timezone
    ln -s ${datadir}/zoneinfo/${DEFAULT_TIMEZONE}      ${D}${sysconfdir}/localtime
else
    bberror "DEFAULT_TIMEZONE is set to an invalid value."
    exit 1
fi
```

I'm assuming that I've got a problem with `${datadir}`, which references `${prefix}`.

Comment: For strategy 1, you can make it with pkg-config path, with this syntax: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH = "$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:${STAGING_DIR_HOST}/usr/lib/pkgconfig"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want to change paths for *everything* or just one recipe?  Not sure why you'd want to change just one recipe to `/usr/local`, but whatever.

If you want to change all of them, then the simple way is to set `prefix` in your `local.conf` or distro configuration (`prefix = "/usr/local"`).

If you want to do it in a particular recipe, then just assigning `prefix="/usr/local"` and `exec_prefix="/usr/local"` in the recipe will work.

These variables are defined in `meta/conf/bitbake.conf`, where you can see that `bindir` is `$exec_prefix/bin`, which is probably why assigning `prefix` didn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried to implement your suggestions but haven't been able to get it working yet. If you could take another look at my my changes and their results, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you set just prefix?  Remember to set exec_prefix too.

Comment: yeah, I did set `exec_prefix` as well.

Comment: @karobar How u managed to solved it. I tried in my case, if I use ur answer it works but it affecting other recipe such as systemd because it also points to the `exec_prefix`. Ross Burton are there any ways other than this method. But my question is still the same.

Comment: If you want to change those variables for just a specific recipe, change them in the recipe itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your first strategy was on the right track, but you were clobbering more than you wanted by changing only "prefix".  If you look in sources/poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf you'll find everything you are clobbering when you set the variable "prefix" to something other than "/usr" (like it was in my case).   In order to modify only the install path with what would manually be the "--prefix" option to configure, I needed to set all the variables listed here in that recipe:

```
prefix="/your/install/path/here"
datadir="/usr/share"
sharedstatedir="/usr/com"
exec_prefix="/usr"
```