# Recipe file installing in different directory

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to add one package into my Yocto image. Currently, I can build my image, but when I install the image, the software is being installed in different directory. Are there any ways to reroute the installation directory. Example the library files should be installed in `/usr/lib64` but its installed in `/usr/lib/`.

I have just figure out that when i build the application .ipk file inside dont have the /usr/lib64/ folder. Which means the files is not being added into it. Are there anyways to solve this?

This is my FILES_${PN} code:

```
FILES_${PN} = "/usr/lib/* \
               /usr/lib64/* \
               /usr/bin/* \
               /etc/* "
```

**Update 1**
This is my do_install code:

```
do_install(){
   cp -r ${WORKDIR}/xxx/* ${WORKDIR}/image/
   install -d ${D}/usr/lib64
   install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/xxx/usr/lib64/* ${D}/usr/lib64/
}
```

All the files listed there are being added into the ipk file except of the `/usr/lib64/*` files. Are this are the right way of doing it. Please can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206207/how-can-i-change-the-installation-path-of-an-autotools-based-bitbake-recipe

Comment: @g0hl1n but mine i am not using autotools

Comment: Nonetheless, if the recipe is written well, it should respect the corresponding `prefix` variables. If not you should add the recipe to you question to get a valid answer.

Comment: @g0hl1n i have edited the question again. can u help me pls

Comment: @g0hl1n what if i need `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`

Comment: Try -D for the last install (i.e. install -D -m 0644 ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can install libraries manually within a recipe:

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/usr/lib64      # ${D}${libdir} maybe also works
    install -m 0644 libexample.a ${D}/usr/lib64
}
```

`D` variable explanation from [Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-D):

> The destination directory. The location in the Build Directory where components are installed by the do_install task. This location defaults to:
>
> ${WORKDIR}/image

You can find the content of the variables via following command (`libdir` variable as example):

```
bitbake -e | grep ^libdir
```

Comment: I tried `bitbake -e | grep ^libdir` command its showing `libdir_native="/usr/lib
libdir_nativesdk="/usr/lib"` Are there anyways to change it to `/usr/lib64`

Comment: what if i need both `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`